# .NET - Containing a regex in another regex

Tags: .net, regex

I have a regex like below:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\{ID=(?<OptionId>\d+),Value=(?<OptionValue>\d+)\}");
```

This is used in many other regex, so I would like to use this by concatenating. That means, I want to make a code like

```
var someRegex = new Regex(@"\{..., Options={use defined regex here}\}");
var anotherRegex = new Regex(@"\{..., Options={use defined regex here}\}");
```

instead of

```
var someRegex = new Regex(@"\{..., Options=\{ID=(?<OptionId>\d+),Value=(?<OptionValue>\d+)\}\}");
var anotherRegex = new Regex(@"\{..., Options=\{ID=(?<OptionId>\d+),Value=(?<OptionValue>\d+)\}\}");
```

How can I insert a regex into another regex, or concat two regex?

Comment: Assign the first regex into a string and add the string where you want it?

Answer (score -1):

First get the pattern you want by string operation, and then create Regex objects.

```cs
var defindedPatt = @"\{ID=(?<OptionId>\d+),Value=(?<OptionValue>\d+)\}";
var somePatt = $@"\{{..., Options={defindedPatt}}}"; // inside $@"", double up a literal { or }
//var somePatt = @"\{..., Options=XXX\}".Replace("XXX", defindedPatt);

var someRegex = new Regex(somePatt);
```